# Automate some MyDlink D-Link cloud actions

Tags: dlink

**Edit TL;DR**

Is there an existing web API to control my D-Link cloud camera instead of using the mydlink Android app? I've check the [D-Link forums](http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=62556.0) and they're not very helpful...

By control I'd like at minima

- Change scene
- Turn on/off privacy status
- Orient camera
- Get camera's privacy status

---

I recently bought a DCS-8525LH in replacement of my old autonomous Dlink camera. Unfortunately all actions are now bound to a single android app called MyDlink doing all the stuff

- Turning on/off the camera's privacy settings
- Orienting
- Detecting movement on/off

There are google assistant/alexa interaction but I want webservices and other automatic behavior. IFTTT is possible but it only uses Movement detection as trigger and On/off switches (not camera) as actions.

I saw a [github project](https://github.com/ageof/MyDlink-API-Python) only showing connected camera to my account and their status that's all.

With a webservice or something more automatable (even Android INTENT if possible), I'd like to

- Turn on/off movement detection
- Orient the camera to a prefixed location
- Get on/off movement detection status

I'll manage myself videos, snapshots and alerts.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help!

Comment: please ask a specific, answerable question

Comment: try contacting dlink and see if they are willing to share the API with you.